# Saving high score using sharedpreference

Tags: android

I am making a game in which I want to save a highest score of a user, all is working in my game but the problem is that when I am exiting a game that high score of user re-sets automatically but I want to make it show to all user until its break and then it will update.

Dialog box which is showed after exiting a game:

```
 private void showGameOverDialog() {





            int previousScore=getHighScore();
            if(playerScore>previousScore){
                saveHighScore();
            }

            //AlertDialog
            //AlertDialog.Builder

            AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Exit Game");
            builder.setMessage("Afraid?");
            //Positive, Negative, Neutral
            //Anonymous Inner Type Interface Implementation
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    exitGame();

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No",

                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            resetGame();
                        }
                    }
            );
            AlertDialog exitDialog=builder.create();
            exitDialog.show();


}
```

Method to get high score

```
 private int getHighScore(){
    SharedPreferences highScore=getSharedPreferences("high",0);
    return highScore.getInt("highScore",0);
}
```

Saving a high score

```
private void saveHighScore(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("data",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor writer=sharedPreferences.edit();

    int displayValue=playerScore;
    //Username-Highscore
    writer.putInt("display",displayValue);

    writer.commit();
    display();

}
```

Displaying a high score

```
 private void display(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("data",0 );
    String userString=sharedPreferences.getString("playerName","Nothing found");
    int highScore=sharedPreferences.getInt("display",0);
    username.setText(userString+"-"+highScore);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your getHighScore() method with this, and try .. it may work

```
 private int getHighScore(){
        SharedPreferences highScore=getSharedPreferences("data",0);
        return highScore.getInt("display",0);
    }
```

Comment: @VishalSharma the name of prefernce file is "data" in which you are saving your high score , so while retrieving the name should be "data" only, not "high", please try the above solution and lemme know if this works.

Comment: @VishalSharma try now... the key you used to save and retrieve the high score was different

Comment: it works,but the things that high score and username is changing when we make a new high score else it is showing default textview.i want to show the highscore everytime.so pls tell me how should do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Save High Score :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

editor.putInt("myHighScore", --your high score--);
editor.commit();
```

Display

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
int myInt = preferences.getInt("myHighScore", -1);
username.setText("High Score : " + myInt);
```

Remove

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

editor.remove("myHighScore");

editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you'r making two shared preferences locations on your app, one is called "high", and the second is called "data", then you're saving the high score value in one and trying to get it from the other. I hope you understood what's wrong now.
here is a sample for better solution.

```
private static final String HIGH_PREF_KEY = "high_score";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("GAME_SHAREDPREF",0);


puplic void saveHighScore(int score){
SharedPreferences.Editor writer = sharedPreferences.edit();
writer.putInt(HIGH_PREF_KEY,score).commit();
}

puplic int getHighScore(){
return sharedPreferences.getInt(HIGH_PREF_KEY, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared Preference with a name, i.e "data". Set High score with a key "highScore" and put your score. When you retrieved get "highScore" and update.

You can use [prefs-droid](https://github.com/binjar/prefs-droid), a wrapper tools for android shared preference.

If you use this library create a shared preference at your Application.

```
Preference.load().using(this).with(PREFERENCE_NAME).prepare();
```

save score using just one line

```
private void saveHighScore(){
    Preference.putInt("highScore", highScore);
}
```

get the score by

```
private int getHighScore(){
    return Preference.getInt("highScore");
}
```

and reset using

```
private void resetScore() {
    Preference.remove("highScore);
}
```

display the score

```
private void display(){
    int highScore = getHighScore();
    username.setText(userString + "-" + highScore);
}
```

Comment: anywhere you want to save or update or remove from shared preference

Answer (score 0):

I did it in my own application as follows, maybe it can help people who read it

**onCreate**

```
    bestScoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bestScoreText);

    sharedPreferences= this.getSharedPreferences("packageName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    bestScore = sharedPreferences.getInt("bestScore", 0);
    bestScoreText.setText("Best Score: " + bestScore);
```

**in the function that runs when the score increases**

```
        score += 1;
        scoreText.setText("Score: "+ score);

        if(bestScore<=score) {
            bestScore = score;
            sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("bestScore", bestScore).apply();
            bestScoreText.setText("Best Score: " + bestScore);
        };
```